# How to auto-restart the preemptible machines?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As you know preemptible machines closes itself after a while. How I can make them restart themselves and keep working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I automatically restart a GCE preemptible instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343498/how-do-i-automatically-restart-a-gce-preemptible-instance)

Comment: Hey David, the answer there is not helpful at all. There is no option to set the pool size to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Pool size would help with maintain the number of preemptible VMs.

Please check this.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups#groups_of_preemptible_instances

Groups of preemptible instances
For workloads where minimal costs are more important than speed of execution, you can reduce the cost of your workload by using preemptible VM instances in your instance group. Preemptible instances last up to 24 hours, and are preempted gracefully—your application has 30 seconds to exit correctly. Preemptible instances can be deleted at any time, but **autohealing will bring the instances back when preemptible capacity becomes available again.**